# pairwise t test or Tukey's test?

Tags: r, anova, post-hoc

I have conducted an experiment with one group of subjects ($n=14$). I have two within-subjects factors and one dependent variable (called Error). The factor "Type" has 2 levels (Baseline, Operant); the factor "Event" has two levels (Action, Tone). The hypothesis is that there is a significant interaction Type*Event, specifically because:

1. $Error_{(Baseline-Action)}-Error_{(Operant-Action)}\leq 0$
2. $Error_{(Baseline-Tone)}-Error_{(Operant_Tone)}\geq0$

So, I first do a two-way repeated measures ANOVA. In R:

```
aov1 <- aov(Error~Type*Event+Error(subj/(Type*Event)), data=my_data)
summary(aov)
```

and the interaction is significant. Now I have to do a multiple comparison. I think it is possible to use both a pairwise t test:

```
# 'inter' is a column created by interaction(my_data$event, my_data$type)
pairwise.t.test(my_data$Error, my_data$inter, paired=T, p.adj="fdr")
```

and a Tukey test:

```
model <- lme(value~inter, random=~1|subj/(inter), data=my_data)
comp <- glht(model, linfct=mcp(te="Tukey"),type="none")
summary(comp)
```

The pairwise confirms my hypothesis 1 and 2, but the Tukey doesn't (it return a significant p-value only for the hypothesis 2). However, I don't know if I'm mistaken something with the commands for the Tukey.

**My questions are:**

- **is this modus operandi correct in my case?**
- **on what basis I can choose which among pairwise t test and Tukey's test is the most appropriate? Are there other alternatives?**

**EDIT.** What is the correct procedure for computing effect size from the output of glht (which give z-scores) and from a pairwise comparison t test (which doens't return the t values)?

Comment: There are many alternatives, even within `pairwise.t.test`. Type ?pairwise.t.test to see them.  Your choice (`fdr` or false discovery rate) applies a different method of multiple comparison control than `tukey`. There is lots of literature on choosing a method, but, as far as I know, no general consensus on which is best.